# Exclude values in DF column

Tags: python, pandas, filter, notin

I have a problem, I want to exclude from a column and drop from my DF all my rows finishing by "99".

I tried to create a list :
filteredvalues = [x for x in df['XX'] if x.endswith('99')]

I have in this list all the concerned rows but how to apply to my DF and drop those rows :

I tried a few things but nothing works :

Lately I tried this :

df = df[df['XX'] not in filteredvalues]

Any help on this?

Comment: `df[~df['XX'].str.endswith('99')]` perhaps?

Comment: Just use `~` operator. `df[~df['XX'].str.endswith('99')]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.str` attribute, with corresponding string methods, to select such items. Then use `~` to negate the result, and filter your dataframe with that:

```
df = df[~df['XX'].str.endswith('99')]
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to to exclude datas ending with 99, how can I manage wit the not in endswith('99')

Comment: Got it, didn't see the operator, thanks guys